# AFNetworking is not working when device is on 3g network but its working when the app is on wifi network

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

`AFNetworking` is not working when device is on 3g network but its working when the app is on wifi network.

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    switch (status) {
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            NSLog(@"Not Reachable");
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            NSLog(@"WiFi");
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            NSLog(@"WWAN");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Other");
            break;
    }
}];
```

In the Reachability status device have network but my web service is not working,

i got an error:-

> "The Internet connection appears to be offline."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

plz go to

**Settings - > mobile Data**

**check Use mobile data for is on For your app.**

**if not then on it.**

:)

Answer (score 0):

If you call webservice in viewDidLoad then I think you should call webservice with some delay

Like

```
[self performSelector:"YOUR webservice" withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

I have seen this problem